# Из файла в многомерный массив

Tags: веб-программирование, php, java, javascript

Как javascriptom открыть файл и изъемать строки для добавления в многомерный массив?
Имеется файл с конфигами, структурированный следующим образом:

```
 version = ‘1.3.15’
 source.id = ‘1’
 source.path = ‘some/path’
 login.remember = ‘1’
 login.name = ‘userName’
 login.password = ‘password’
 awful.layout = ‘split’
 awful.layout.suit = ‘tile’
```

Comment: однако это забавно. Многие уже привыкли к тому, что сюда приходит какой-нибудь студент и просит сделать за него его работу. Но вот чтобы приходил и просил сказать, что это за работа - такого я здесь еще не видел

Comment: Вам нужно : написать программу, которая будет брать конфиг, перебирать его и складывать в многомерный массив. Используйте регулярки.

Comment: А имеет ли браузерный javascript доступ к файловой системе?

Comment: @VladD а что позволит все это сделать php? html? если php то как???с помощью каких функций?

Comment: @Анатолийй: Для начала, скажите, где бежит код, и где находится конфиг-файл. Варианты:

* Конфиг лежит на сервере, код php или js бежит на сервере — прочитать можно.
* Конфиг лежит на сервере, код php или js бежит на машине клиента — прочитать невозможно в принципе, надо слать запрос коду, бегущему на сервере, чтобы он прочитал.
* Конфиг лежит на машине клиента, код js бежит в браузере клиента — прочитать невозможно, так как браузер клиента не пустит вас в файловую систему. Разве что положить конфиг в cookie.

Comment: @Vlad или fileReader  но тогда клиент должен сам указать файл.

Comment: @VladD  первый вариант

Comment: @Анатолийй: У вас js бежит на _сервере_? Тогда проблем быть не должно. А каким скриптовым фреймворком пользуетесь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаешь пустой массив для результатов. Проходишся циклом по каждой строке конфига, делишь ее на левую и правую часть от знака `=`. Левую часть делишь точками. Полученный массив из левой части перебираешь по очереди с проверкой на предмет создан ли соответствующий ключ в массиве с результатом. Если нет, то создаешь. В конце в последний созданный элемент пишешь значение из правой части. Ну и все, после прохода последней строки конфига массив с результатами готов.

Как-то так :)